# Comment traduire l'expression anglaise « silver bullet » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Souvent utilisé dans le domaine informatique, sur un site comme [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22silver%20bullet%22), l'expression « silver bullet » a été démocratisée par l'article [*No Silver Bullet — Essence and Accidents of Software Engineering*](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~cah/G51ISS/Documents/NoSilverBullet.html).

Cette expression fait référence au fait qu'un loup-garou ne peut être tué que par une balle d'argent, et donc qu'en terme informatique, il n'existe pas de solution aussi efficace et unanimement reconnue pour être parfaite — comme peut l'être une balle en argent.

Connaissez-vous une expression se rapprochant en français, ne serait-ce qu'un petit peu, ou est-on condamné à abandonner cette expression lors d'une traduction ?

[Citation de Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bullet) :

> *The term has been adopted into a general metaphor, where "silver
>   bullet" refers to any straightforward solution perceived to have
>   extreme effectiveness. The phrase typically appears with an
>   expectation that some new technological development or practice will
>   easily cure a major prevailing problem.*

Liens Wikipédia à propos de l'article : [anglais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet), [français](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pas_de_balle_en_argent).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de traduction parfaite pour cette expression. On peut utiliser **« remède miracle »**, « solution miracle », « recette miracle », …

« Panacée » est parfois employé, mais il a une connotation d'universalité que *silver bullet* n'a pas forcément :

> **silver bullet**
>   a bullet made of silver, used in fiction as a supposedly magical method of killing werewolves.
>   • a simple and seemingly magical solution to a complicated problem
>
> <sup>(*New Oxford American Dictionary*)</sup>

Noter le « **a** complicated problem ».

Comment: Ou juste _miracle_, parfois. « Y'a pas de miracle, va falloir y aller à pied! »

Comment: En fait tu aurais d'ailleurs pu commencer ta réponse par _Il n'y a pas de traduction miracle pour cette expression._

Answer (score 9):

« Panacée universelle », parfois réduit en « [panacée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/panac%C3%A9e) » (en particulier quand la notion d'universalité n'est pas bien venue, malheureusement elle reste présente), n'a pas toutes les connotations mais me semble être l'expression française la plus proche.

Comment: "Panacée universelle" me semble un pléonasme.

Comment: C'est peut-être justement parce que c'est un pléonasme que c'est autant utilisé.

Comment: Jamais entendu "panacée universelle". La BDL indique en effet que c'est un pléonasme : http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2113

Answer (score 9):

En France, on emploie souvent l'expression "*Il n'y a pas de baguette magique !*" pour affirmer qu'il n'existe pas de remède miracle à un problème posé.

Comment: Il y a un rapport entre ce "Silver bullet" et le "there is no silver bullet"?  Parce que ce n'est pas évident comme ça. C'est un anglicisme mal compris ou c'est utilisé dans ce sens aussi en anglais?

Comment: Non, ce dernier Silver Bullet (qui est utilisé dans les deux langues) n'a pas de rapport avec le "there's no Silver Bullet". "There's no Silver Bullet" n'est en rapport qu'avec "Il n'y a pas de baguette magique".  Par contre le second "Silver Bullet" peut être source de confusion, car il est répandu dans le domaine informatique auquel cette question fait référence. Mon second paragraphe doit donc plutôt s'interpréter comme "attention, il y a un faux ami".

Comment: tu as des exemples de son utilisation avec ce sens en anglais? (et même en français en fait aussi)

Comment: Du second? Oui bien sur: "Guys, I'm afraid we have just received a Silver Bullet". Je l'ai malheureusement entendu il y a peu, et nous l'avons réglé... toutes affaires cessantes. Tandis qu'en interne, on ne s'y référait que sous la forme "Silver Bullet", comme chaque tâche de ce genre, même non présentée comme telle mais comme "tâche prioritaire". (ie: "attention, on a un Silver Bullet au tableau" [des tâches])

Comment: Je suis curieux parce que je ne l'ai jamais entendu ou vu avec ce sens là. Si on me disait "We've received a Silver Bullet", je comprendrais "on a reçu quelque chose qui peut nous tuer".

Comment: Je comprends... et je t'avoue qu'en recherchant sur internet je ne trouve que le premier sens. Vocabulaire "corporate", mais partagé par plusieurs sociétés tout de même (du moins la mienne et celles avec qui nous travaillons)? En tous cas la signification "qqch qui peut nous tuer" est appropriée: car "si on ne le fait pas tout de suite, on est dedans". Peut-être que ce faux amis est trop rare pour nécessiter d'être mentionné, j'ai envie d'éditer ma réponse pour n'en garder que la première partie afin de ne pas rendre les choses plus complexes que nécessaire. Qu'en penses-tu?

Comment: oui je pense que ça sera plus clair, finalement le sens des deux est peut-être le même

Comment: Ah, @F'x l'a fait pour moi peu après notre échange! Merci à vous deux :)

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression ; je soupçonne que c'est assez local.

Answer (score 4):

Personne ne semble encore avoir proposé *la solution magique*

Le parti des Verts (http://greens.eu) a traduit

> However, there is no silver bullet for solving the majority of the problems that energy and climate policy is facing today.

par

> Il n'existe cependant pas de solution magique permettant de résoudre la majorité des problèmes qui se posent aujourd'hui à la politique

Comment: A mon avis, "solution miracle" serait meilleur car beaucoup plus usité.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'existe pas de panacée.
Il n'existe aucune recette miracle.